# ./gradle bundlerelease not generating aab

Tags: react-native

I was trying to build an app via ./gradle bundlerelease
got an error everytime:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android\src\reactnative\java\io\invertase\firebase\app\ReactNativeFirebaseAppInitProvider.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".reactnativefirebaseappinitprovider";
           ^
```

symbol:   variable APPLICATION_ID
location: class BuildConfig
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrad the gradle to 3.6.0 (in `build.gradle`) and rebuild the project.

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0')
```